# Pronunciation of "sa" and "ça"

Tags: prononciation

Is the pronunciation of "sa" (her) *precisely* the same as the pronunciation of "ça" (it)?

Does it "feel" the same to a native french speaker, or is it definably, or indefinably, different?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In France the pronunciation is **exactly** the same : *[sa]*. But the context will always give you a hint about which one is used.

---

En France, la prononciation est **exactement** la même : *[sa]*. C'est le contexte qui permettra de déterminer lequel des deux est utilisé.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand about the context providing the meaning.  I wanted to checked if it is like "f" (farm) and "ph" (pharmacy) in English, which are pronounced exactly the same, or if a French person hears or feels them differently.

Comment: @GreenAsJade, it feels exactly the same.  Misspellings are common, especially with children.

Comment: @StephaneGimenez : merci pour la correction! maintenant que j'y pense, dans le Nord, *ça* ne serait-il pas aussi prononcé *[sɑ]* alors que *sa* conserverait la prononciation *[sa]*?

Comment: I don't know about France, but in Belgium there are people (me included) for which the only difference between /a/ and /ɑ/ is one of length and it isn't made for all the words which dictionaries say contains an /ɑ/. _Sa_, _ça_ and _çà_ are perfect homophones for me.

Comment: I don't agree at all the sound is different, try to pronounce garson and garçon, you will notice a difference (at least in the common pronunciantion)

Comment: @maazza And how would that be different? (Not sure how I would pronounce *garson* since it's a made up word...)

Answer (score 10):

The [other answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11976/1129) is valid only for European French.

In Quebec, the pronunciation of *ça* in stressed position (as in "Je veux ça") is [sɑ], but [sa] in unstressed position (e.g., "Ça va", [sa vɑ].) However, *sa* is always [sa], even if it is stressed: "C'est *sa* brosse [i.e., à elle] que je veux."

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes they sound same. But I would say that depends on where you find it in the sentence. At the end, like when to show something, the pronunciation could be frank. The sound is cutt, (like →).

But at the beginning of a sentence it could finish lower (like ↘).
In other terms it could be compared to a sinus or square form ending.

For these words that's not so important but this is a good approach for French and all latin languages I think.

In fact, starting with a strong "Ça", like you can say "ça" to show something in a sentence's ending, could be interpreted as intransigent/non-polite. Because the "square sinus" has been used.

The "sa" stay mostly neutral, but owns somes variations only in familiar/street speaking. Because it's feminine, and because it's possessive, it can be used as a punctuation in sentence, a rolling-over or a point of turning in sentence. On this case you can hold the "s" a bit longer and even only on this case finish ↗ with no mouth cut.

Answer (score 0):

In Québec, there are two pronunciations, as indicated above. But I am not sure that it's stressed vs unstressed that makes the difference. Consider:

Ça [sa] ne fait rien. (Rhymes with « ma ».)

Donne-moi ça [sɑ]. (Rhymes with « chat ».)

Ça [sɑ], ce n'est pas difficile. (Rhymes with « chat ».)

I think that it rhymes with « ma » when it is a subject and with « chat » when it is either an object (direct or indirect) or in apposition. My basis for this is near-native-speaker intuition and consultation with other French speakers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).